# How auto rebuild and reload browser works in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

hi I am a newbie in reactJS and am learning reactjs recently by kickstarting from the **`create-react-app`** and modifiying it . My doubt is that how the **`create-react-app`** detects the changes in files and autimatically rebuilds them . I used a normal **`nodejs + react + webpack`** app  and in that i have to manually specify the **`npm run build`** and **`node start`** in the **`package.json`** like as

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "node server"
  },
```

in case the above for the create-react-app differ as

```
 "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "npm run build-css && run-p -ncr watch-css start-js",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "run-s -n build-css build-js",
    "build-js": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "run-s -n build-css test-js",
    "test-js": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "build-css": "node-less-chokidar src",
    "watch-css": "node-less-chokidar src --watch",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

What makes the **`create-react-app`** and a normal **`node+webpack+react`** app differ in rebuilding the source ? (Starting the server seems not a deal because once its started it will be runing on a port for both cases . For Server restart both apps needed to kill the process and start again . So building the source is my only concern) . Any help is appreciated .